# Help finding the limit of a sequence defined by a sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I've been stuck with the following problem for some time. I need to find the limit of the sequence $\lbrace a_n\rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$, where

$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2 + k^2}$$

This was found in a test, and the answers all assumed that the sequence converges, so all we have to do is find the limit. I will post the options at the end of the question.

I managed to bound the possible solution between $1/2$ and $1$, by taking into account that $k\in[1,n]$, but this only reduces the problem to choosing between three options, I think.

The other thing I tried was to express the denominator as the product $(n+ik)(n-ik)$, so the fraction simplifies to:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n+ik} +\frac{1}{n-ik}\right)$$

But I don't know how to continue from here.

THE POSSIBLE ANSWERS ARE:

A) $1/2$

B)$\pi/4$

C) $\pi/2$

D) $\log(2)$

E) $2\log(2)$

AND THE CORRECT ONE IS THE Xth LETTER OF THE ALPHABET, WHERE $X^2+5 = 9$.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the perfect trick for this kind of question, it will undoubtedly help me with similar exercises.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: By dividing the numerators and denominators by $\frac{1}{n^2}$, note the following:

$$a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \Big(\frac{1}{n} \times  \frac{1}{1+(i/n)^2}\Big).$$

But $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n  \Big(\frac{1}{n} \times \frac{1}{1+(i/n)^2}\Big) \ = \ \int^1_0 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}.$$

Then to evaluate the above integral, use the substitution $x = \tan(u)$ and thus $dx = sec(u) du$ to get

$$\int^1_0 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int^{\tan^{-1}(1)}_0 \frac{\sec^2(u)du}{1+\tan^2(u)}$$
$$ = \ \int^{\tan^{-1}(1)}_0 \frac{\sec^2(u)du}{\sec^2(u)} \ldots$$

Can you finish from here, to get $\tan^{-1}(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this by Riemann sum:

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, then $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+(\frac{k}{n})^2}=\frac{1-0}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(0+\frac{1-0}{n}k).$$

Since $f(x)$ is continus, we have $$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}f\left(a+\dfrac{b-a}{n}k\right) = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$

So
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=arctan(1)-arctan(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$